# Gradle fails injecting dependencies into subprojects using fileTree

Tags: dependency-injection, gradle, subproject

Maybe I'm missing something about the way Gradle works. What I have here is a parent project, which only contains configuration, i.e. there won't be any artifact being built when building it, it merely manages and builds all its subprojects.

Now the subprojects share some dependency configuration, so I figured what I would do in the root project's build.gradle is:

```
subprojects {
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
  }    
}
```

that, however, does not work, it fails with a rather obscure error message:

> A problem occurred evaluating root
>   project 'qype-android' Cause: No
>   signature of method:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultConfigurableFileTree)
>   values: [file set 'lib'] Possible
>   solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

after some trial and error, I could "fix" this issue by applying the 'java' plugin to the parent project.

How come? I don't see anywhere from the Gradle docs that a `fileTree` dependency requires the Java plugin. Even so, why would I need it on the project that is injecting the configuration, as opposed to on the project that is being configured (note that the subprojects all apply the Java plugin themselves)?

Does this mean that if I have N different subprojects that are all of varying natures, and apply different plugins, that the parent projects must always apply the set of *all* plugins beings used somewhere to itself, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the `fileTree` that requires 'java' plugin.

The error message is complaining about undefined `compile` dependency configuration. Java plugin defines this configuration for you, so that you can add dependencies (including your fileTree) to it.

Comment: I see -- thanks. However, I stil find it awkward that I must apply the Java plugin to the parent project, when it's not a Java project...

Comment: But you don't have to apply java plugin to the root project: just move `apply plugin:'java'` instruction to `subproject` section.

Comment: that's odd. I didn't put it there, but in every subproject's build.gradle, I called `apply plugin: 'java'`. What's the difference of doing that in the `subprojects` block, compared to doing it in the subproject's build files?

Comment: Default evaluation order for multi-project builds is "top-down" with alphabetical order for projects on the same depth. In your case, root project is getting evaluated (meaning build.gradle is executed) *before* any subprojects. Therefore, `apply plugin:'java'` is not yet executed for subproject by the time gradle tries to execute `subproject` section of the root project's build.gradle. Thats it.